# How to create and add user with password in alpine Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

The following `Dockerfile` works fine for Ubuntu:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ARG user=hakond
ARG home=/home/$user
RUN useradd --create-home -s /bin/bash $user \
        && echo $user:ubuntu | chpasswd \
        && adduser $user sudo

WORKDIR $home
USER $user
COPY --chown=$user entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

where `entrypoint.sh` is

```
#! /bin/bash
exec bash
```

How can I do the same in Alpine? I tried:

```
FROM alpine:3.12
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
ARG user=hakond
ARG home=/home/$user
RUN addgroup -S docker
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home $home \
    --ingroup docker \
    $user
WORKDIR $home
USER $user
COPY chown=$user entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

But this fails to build:

```
$ docker build -t alpine-user .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/12 : FROM alpine:3.12
 ---> a24bb4013296
Step 2/12 : SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ce9a303c96c8
Step 3/12 : RUN apk add --no-cache bash
 ---> Running in e451a2481846
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.2_p20200523-r0)
(2/4) Installing ncurses-libs (6.2_p20200523-r0)
(3/4) Installing readline (8.0.4-r0)
(4/4) Installing bash (5.0.17-r0)
Executing bash-5.0.17-r0.post-install
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r16.trigger
OK: 8 MiB in 18 packages
Removing intermediate container e451a2481846
 ---> 7b5f7f87bdf6
Step 4/12 : ARG user=hakond
 ---> Running in 846b4b12856e
Removing intermediate container 846b4b12856e
 ---> a0453cb6706e
Step 5/12 : ARG home=/home/$user
 ---> Running in 06550ad3f550
Removing intermediate container 06550ad3f550
 ---> 994d71fb0281
Step 6/12 : RUN addgroup -S docker
 ---> Running in 70aaec6f40e0
Removing intermediate container 70aaec6f40e0
 ---> 5188ed7b234c
Step 7/12 : RUN adduser     --disabled-password     --gecos ""     --home $home     --ingroup docker     $user
 ---> Running in ff36a7f7e99b
Removing intermediate container ff36a7f7e99b
 ---> 97f481916feb
Step 8/12 : WORKDIR $home
 ---> Running in 8d7f0411d6e3
Removing intermediate container 8d7f0411d6e3
 ---> 5de66f4b5d4e
Step 9/12 : USER $user
 ---> Running in ac4abac7c3a8
Removing intermediate container ac4abac7c3a8
 ---> dffd2185df1f
Step 10/12 : COPY chown=$user entrypoint.sh .
COPY failed: stat /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/docker-builder615220199/chown=hakond: no such file or directory
```

Comment: You generally don't do this at all.  You can trivially retrieve the password in clear text using `docker history`, and the single process a container runs isn't usually a login-type process.  What's the actual thing the container is eventually going to do?

Comment: I am trying to simulate a normal user environment (as it would be when not running from docker). So the user should be a normal user (not a root user) and have a home directory and a password. When the environment is setup like this, I can test installing modules in a pure environment for example for debugging purposes..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You created your new user successfully, you just wrote `chown` instead of `--chown` in your `COPY` command.

Your Dockerfile should look like:

```
FROM alpine:3.12
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
ARG user=hakond
ARG home=/home/$user
RUN addgroup -S docker
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home $home \
    --ingroup docker \
    $user
WORKDIR $home
USER $user
COPY --chown=$user entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```